# Store multiple data into Service Array from Controller?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

This should be relatively simple using a getter and setter though i am not sure how to setup the getter and setter properly.

Functionality is like this:

1. User clicks on list item which will init registerChat function which will store the chat data into the array.
2. Chat will display data using the getChat function.
3. User can click on more than one chat item to store more data into array.
4. killChat will execute when use clicks close on chat item.

Service:

```
app.factory('chatbox',['$http',function($http){

  var total_chats = 0;
  var registeredChats = [];

  var registerChat = function(userid) {
    //Places Chat into variable
  };

  var getChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat for the Controller
  };

  var killChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat from Variable
  };

}]);
```

I would like to be able to store data into this Service from Any Controller containing the service?

Answer (score 0):

You need your functions to be defined as member of service. Thus not `var` but `this.`

```
  this.registerChat = function(userid) {
    //Places Chat into variable
  };

  this.getChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat for the Controller
  };

  this.killChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat from Variable
  };
```

Then you will be able to use `chatbox` in controller

```
 angular.controller('Controller1', function($scope, chatbox){ 
      $scope.kill = function(userId, chat){
          chatbox.killChat(userId, chat);
      }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it :

```
app.service('chatbox',['$http',function($http){
  var service = {
      getChats : getChats,
      setChats : setChats
  };
  return service;

  var total_chats = 0;
  var registeredChats = [];

  function getChats(){
      //Insert logic here
  }

  function setChats(){
      // Insert logic here
  }


}]);
```

Comment: And get complaints from jslint :) for declaring functions after usage

Comment: jslint is stupid in that case. I don't care if my functions are hoisted. It's more clear that way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.factory('chatbox',['$http',function($http){

 var total_chats = 0;

  var registeredChats = [];

  var registerChat = function(userid) {
    //Places Chat into variable
    registerChat.push(userId);
    total_chats = total_chats + 1;
  };

  var getChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat for the Controller
    return registered_chats;
  };

  var killChat = function(userid) {
    //Gets Chat from Variable
    ... you get the idea
  };

  var toReturn = {
    getChat: getChat,
    registerChat: registerChat,
    killChat: killChat
};

return toReturn
```

}]);